# How to generalize a value to other rows in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a lot of rows.

Each row has data about a person, and a person can have 1 or more rows.

There is a column which is not perfectly filled, so for a single person it is sometimes `NA` even if the value is known.

I want to generalize the known value to every other rows of the selected person, and put `NA` if there is no value for this person.

Sample :

```
df = data.frame(person=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3), val=c(7,7,7, NA,5,NA, NA,NA,NA))
```

Expected output :

```
df = data.frame(person=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3), val=c(7,7,7, 5,5,5, NA,NA,NA))
```

**How can I achieve this ?**

PS : I love dplyr so feel free to use it.

Comment: You can use `fill` from `tidyr` i.e. `df %>% group_by(person) %>% fill(val, .direction = 'up')`  If needed `%>% fill(val, .direction = 'down')`
  I think a similar question was asked today

Comment: Fill is not enough because there is no defined direction, I changed a bit my sample, take a look

Comment: You can use both `up` and `down` i.e. `df %>% group_by(person) %>% fill(val, .direction = 'up') %>% fill(val, .direction = 'down')`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could use `ave`

```
ave(df$val, df$person, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1]   7   7   7   5   5   5 NaN NaN NaN
```